# How to upload a multiple images using vue.js filepond

Tags: filepond

Hi all Here I am using vue.js filepond for multi uploading images. So in my code I am able to upload only one image but here I want to upload multiple images and also I want to create a access point to pass the uploaded images in backend to save the data. So here I am trying alot but i am not able to do that. So please help to sort out this issue

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.css"/>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview/dist/filepond-plugin-image-preview.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <file-pond></file-pond>
    </div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond-plugin-image-preview"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-filepond@6"></script>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        components: {
          FilePond: vueFilePond.default(FilePondPluginImagePreview),
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set `allowMultiple` to `true`?

Comment: where in data I have give allowMultiple  to true

Comment: `<file-pond v-bind:allow-multiple="true"></file-pond>` see example snippet on gh page https://github.com/pqina/vue-filepond